# javaScript include contains ghost data

Tags: javascript, nginx

I encounter a strange problem i cannot explain, hopefully somebody has an idea what might be the cause.

We are testing a JavaScript application running on 4 computers with each 4 separate chrome windows opened.

The application is created in vanilla JavaScript, because is it running on very low spec computers in production.

The applications index.html is served by nginx and includes a player.js JavaScript file with all the needed code.

All is running fine, but every 2 days or so the following happens:

Inside the player.js javascript file that is included by the index.html appears the following out of the blue..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 05:25:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 268068
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "594dc946-41724"
Last-Modified: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 02:07:02 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

This results in a JavaScript error which crashes the application.

Below i have included a piece of the JavaScript file that is being loaded from the server to get a idea of where the unwanted code suddenly appears.

```
           ping: function ping() {

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', app.config.endpoints.heartbeat);

                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            var status = xhr.response;
                            if (status) resolve(true); // is true resolve
                            if (!status) reject(false); // not true
                        } else {
                            app.errorHandler.warn("not able to ping " + app.config.endpoints.heartbeat);
                            reject(false);
                        }
                    };

                    xhr.onerror = function () {
                        app.errorHandler.warn("there was a xhr.error during ping to " + app.config.endpoints.heartbeat);
                        reject(false);
                    };

                    xhr.send();
                });
            }
        };
    }());
}(window, window[app]);HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 05:25:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 268068
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "594dc946-41724"
Last-Modified: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 02:07:02 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Accept-Ranges: bytes

"use strict";

+function (window) {
    /** Register the app name to use as the global `app` scope. */
    window.app = "edgeclient";
    /** The actual object that represents the `app` */
    window[app] = {};
}(window);
"use strict";

var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

+function (window, app) {
    "use strict";
    /**
     * @description
     * Publish the `pageload` event on `DOMContentLoaded`.
     */

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        app.event.publish("pageload");
    }, false);
```

Comment: Didnt you forget about applying `return;` after running `resolve(true);`?
The same applies for `reject();`

Comment: Thanks for a possible solution, but when using a promise you don't have to return anything but the promise  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise @sunpietro

Comment: So return promise :)

Comment: @sunpietro that is what is done, if i run the ping function it is possible to do the following

`ping().then(function() {
  // all loaded
}, function() {
  // one or more failed
});`

but i need an idea of what could have happend, it is all running fine at the moment, it could also have been an browser issue